# App refresh needed to access relationship objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my app I have two entities `Items` and `Lists` where items can belong to one list and list can have several items.

When I create a `Lists` managed object and assign to it's relationship the item object (that I previously created) cannot be retrieved through its relationship. When I print it out in console I get this:

[image]

As you can see in the first picture `has_items` does contain an item and printing out the `has_items` returns null (printed out at the bottom of the picture). However, when I refresh my app and try accessing it again it works fine but now I get a relation fault thing which I know it's not an error or faulty thing and it should be that way.

Please see picture two to see how the prints changes after a refresh.

[image]

How can I fix that? (rephrase of the problem: to be able to save an object to a relationship property and after saving the context retrieving the object without refreshing the app).

EDIT: code is here

```
List *newList = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newList setValue:obj[@"list_name"] forKey:@"list_name"];
[newList addHas_membersObject:self.currentMember];
[newList setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"current_list"];
[newList setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"is_synced"];
[newList setValue:obj[@"objectId"] forKey:@"object_identifier"];

[context insertObject:newList];

[self saveContext:context WithCompletion:^ {NSLog(@"completion being handled");
    Items *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newItem setValue:item[@"item_detail"] forKey:@"item_detail"];
    [newItem setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"is_synced"];
    [newItem setValue:item.createdAt forKey:@"date_added"];
    [newItem setValue:item[@"is_checked"] forKey:@"is_checked"];
    [newItem setValue:newList forKey:@"belong_to_list"];

    [context insertObject:newItem];

    [newList addHas_itemsObject:newItem];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    NSLog(@"item saved");
}
```

Comment: Cannot see images since too small. Also add some useful code. Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted first thank you for the edit. if you want to see the pictures control click and open in another tab. The pictures are big in width. if still have problems i'll upload new ones. as for the code i'll try adding that now. Thank you

Comment: So, after saving you should do `[newList valueForKey:@"has_items"]` and you will be able to access your new objects. A `NSSet` of items will be available at that point. Could you please format the code? Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted AHHHHHHH I WILL NEVER LEARN! my app is syncing between core data and the cloud. at some point if the user is old but reinstalled the app i want to restore his data. and guess what was the problem? i misplaced the array of lists and i didn't initialised it when restoring data. *face palm* anyway thank you and i won't  let you go without some points i guess this is the second time you help me out. type in the answer and i'll check it as the correct one.

Comment: You're welcome. And not a problem. You could just reply to your own answer in order that other people can see the solution you found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in my code I forgot to initialize the array that should hold the objects and I'm always returning null. So always remember to initialise your arrays (personally I'll never learn that).

Comment: Do not remember to mark is as answered whenever possible. Thanks again.